# Extract multiple PDF forms into once excel file

Tags: pdf, forms

I have a one page PDF file which is used by our users for registration. Is there anyway I can extract form values from all the PDFs filled out by users in a single excel file, at once?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to run a macro though. What have you tried already?